# Convergence of ecutwfc for Sulphur vacant 221MoS2 monolayer

Tags: quantum-espresso

I optimize the ecutwfc for one sulphur vacancy on 221 MoS2 monolayer in Quantum Espresso. From the attached data, which is the correct converged ecutwfc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give a unit for energy here?  I forget what QE reports as its natural unit.

Comment: You can take 50 Ry. See the difference between two adjacent energies. The difference is less than several meV. Even your conference is achieved below 50Ry.

Comment: While the figure is obviously fine as an image, it would better if you include the table as text rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your criterion for convergence. For many applications convergence up to 1 meV is more than enough, and then the ecutwfc of 70eV is perfect, and probably 60eV is also good enough.
For other applications convergence up to ~10meV is excellent, and then you could even go lower towards 50eV or even 40eV.

Fromy experience, for monolayer MoS2 70eV is usually a good value to use.